# How can I search with typeahead if my selected class was not loaded in DOM but appended later on

Tags: jquery

I've used typeahed lots of times, it works like a charm, but now I need something slightly different. If you have already used typeahead you know that you have to select a class of an input via jquery. It will grab the contents of that input and automatically search for that string with help of php. My problem is I need various searches around my page, so I'm inserting new inputs via jquery's append, which already works, but as these new inputs haven't been loaded with the DOM I simply can't select them. I've read some stuff about on('change') to solve that but I can't work it out.

Here's my typeahead code

```
$('input.typeaheadEmail').typeahead({
   minLength: 1,
   source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get('buscarNome', { query: query }, function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          data = $.parseJSON(data);
          return process(data);
      });
   }
});
```

And here's my append code

```
$("#adicionarExecutores").click (function () {
    $('#divExecutores').append('<input type="email" class="executor typeaheadEmail form-control" style="padding-top: 5px !important;" name="podemVer[]" placeholder="nome@dominio.com.br" autocomplete="off" value=""/>');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. Once I can't call .typeaheadEmail after load, I used .on('keyup') and wrapped my code around a function. It's hacky but it works.

```
$('#divExecutores').on('keyup', '.typeaheadEmail', function() {
        typeaheadEmail();
    });

    function typeaheadEmail() {
        $('input.typeaheadEmail').typeahead({
                       minLength: 3,
                        source:  function (query, process) {
                                return $.get('buscarUsuario', { query: query }, function (data) {
                                         console.log(data);
                                         data = $.parseJSON(data);
                                        return process(data);
                                });
                        }
        });

    }
```